# Web View Not Saving HTML5 Local Storage Settings

Tags: objective-c, xcode, webview

I have a web app that works fine in Safari (it uses local storage and saves the settings and restores them).

I created a web view in Xcode 4.5.2 that loads my web app. I know by default web view doesn't support local storage so I added code to enable it but now the app doesn't work at all.

My code in AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    WebPreferences *prefs = [WebView preferences];.
    [prefs _setLocalStorageDatabasePath:@"~/Library/TestApp/LocalStorage"];


    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"html"];
    NSURL* fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
    [self.webView.mainFrame loadRequest:request];
}

@end
```

This part is what I added to enable local storage:

```
    WebPreferences *prefs = [WebView preferences];.
    [prefs _setLocalStorageDatabasePath:@"~/Library/TestApp/LocalStorage"];
```

I get the following error: "Expected expression" - "No known class method for selector 'preferences'"

Comment: Did you set a delegate for the web view?

Answer (score 3):

`-preferences` is an instance method on `WebView`, not a class method. You'll want to do `WebPreferences *prefs = [self.webView preferences]` to retrieve the preferences for your `WebView`. In addition to calling `-[WebPreferences _setLocalStorageDatabasePath:]`, I believe that you'll also want to call `-[WebPreferences setLocalStorageEnabled:]` to ensure that local storage is enabled.

Comment: I added the following code: WebPreferences *prefs = [self.webView preferences]; -[WebPreferences _setLocalStorageDatabasePath:@"~/Library/TestApp/LocalStorage"]; -[WebPreferences setLocalStorageEnabled:]; but it is flagging @"~/Library/TestApp/LocalStorage" and saying "Invalid argument type 'id' to unary expression - No known class method for selector '_setLocalStorageDatabasePath:'

Comment: I didn't provide code for you to copy and paste in to your application, I provided the names of the messages that you need to send and the type of object to which you should send them. It's up to you to type the code that sends them.

Comment: I followed this tutorial: http://www.lostdecadegames.com/completing-your-native-mac-osx-app-built-in-h/ which is for an older SDK but I assumed the code (which I included in my question) only needed to be slightly modified, I didn't realize that it was way off.