# Is it possible to enable local storage in a web view using a public API?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, webview, xcode4.5

I'm new to Xcode and Objective-C. I asked a question earlier about why my local storage code was not working but now based on further research it seems like local storage may not be supported with a public API in Xcode 4.5.2?

I followed this tutorial: http://www.lostdecadegames.com/completing-your-native-mac-osx-app-built-in-h/ to try and enable local storage but it's for Xcode 4.0.1 and I'm using version of Xcode 4.5.2. I got the web view to load my HTML5 web app but I have not figured out how to enable local storage.

My question is, is it possible to enable local storage in a web view using a public API in Xcode 4.5.2? I've read yes and no and how someone would do it but have yet to find an actual working example? I also found a number of questions about it on Stack Overflow but they reference older versions of Xcode so they don't work any longer.

Comment: What happens when you try to instructions on that page? Does it produce compile or runtime error? Does it behave in a way you dont expect?

Comment: I get a number of errors... Here's my original question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867303/web-view-not-saving-html5-local-storage-settings) with how I modified it and the exact errors I got. I got a response that I was unable to figure out how to implement. I was assuming that I would only have to add a line or two of code to my project to enable it?

Answer (score -1):

No, both methods on WebPreferences related to local storage are SPI.